# Strange error with arrayfun

Tags: matlab

I have the following line of code:

```
sample_density=[4;5];
Grid=arrayfun(@(x)linspace(0,2*pi,x),sample_density,'UniformOutput','off');
```

The anonymous function `@(x)linspace(0,2*pi,x)` works fine. So stepping through the code with a loop manually works. But running the above code results in the following error:

```
Error using arrayfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 2 in dimension 1. Input #3 has size 1
```

I am clueless as to what the message means. There doesn't seem to be any way to locate where the message is triggered. Does anyone know what "Input #3" might be?

On face value, the situation described in the message is simply not the case. Why does the code not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the name-value pair for `'UniformOutput'` wrong.

The argument is a boolean (`true` or `false`), not the string `'on'` or `'off'`. The following syntax should work:

```
sample_density=[4;5];
Grid=arrayfun(@(x)linspace(0,2*pi,x),sample_density,'UniformOutput',false);
```